# Convert List<String> to List<Employee> or List<MyCustomClass>

Tags: java, json, list, java-8

I am getting a List as output from my database, which is like json array. I want to convert the same into List using java 8. I am trying to use the below code snippet but it gives me compilation error. Cannot convert from List to List

```
List<String> employeeList = getEmployeeList();
return (List<Employee>) employeeList;
```

Sample json array

```
 {"employees":[    
        {"name":"Ram", "email":"ram@gmail.com", "age":23},    
        {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyam23@gmail.com", "age":28},  
        {"name":"John", "email":"john@gmail.com", "age":33},    
        {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "age":41}   
    ]}
```

Comment: you might want to look into object mapping using libraries like Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jackson objectMapper to achieve that:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Employee> employeeList = mapper.readValue(yourJsonString, new TypeReference<List<Employee>>(){});
```

Note that `yourJsonString` is your json data